# Reactjs and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, reactjs, server

I am new to react and node , i have kept my JSON file in the server and using node i am fetching it . I need to render it in react component . 
problem statement : - 
Simple website in react that gets data from server , data can be simple JSON file kept in server . ON click of list item from nav menu , you should get the data from JSON .

Eg:
if you click home link , you should get title and content displayed 
if you click on about , you should get title and content displayed
if you click on contact , you should get title and content displayed.

/* JSON file */

```
{
        "home":{"title":"Welcome to home page","content": "welcome to the webpage."},
        "about":{"title":"we are a venture funding firm","content":"Lets work together to achieve ideas and profits"},
        "contact":{"title":"Below is the address to get in touch","content": "<div>Street no 10</div><div>Domlur</div><div> Bangalore</div><div> Pin 560037</div>"},
        "recent":{"title":"Welcome to the news section","newsArray":[{"title":"we are live on October","news": "The website is live on feb"},{"title":"UI courses launched","news": "we have introduced a UI course live now"}] }
    }
```

/**** React Code ******/

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg' ;
import './App.css' ;
import './style.css' ; 


class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (

      <div className="wrapper">
    <div className="banner">
      <img  width = "960px" height = "200px"  src= {require('./images/banner.jpg')}/>
      <h2> A simple layout using css and html</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="main">

    </div>
    <div className="menu">
      <h2>Side Menu</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href = "#" id = "home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#" id = "about">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#" id = "contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#" id = "recent">Recent News</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div className="copyright">
      <p>Copyright 2010, Some Company</p>
    </div>

  </div>
    );
  }
}export default App;
```

/***** Node code *****/

```
var fs = require('fs');
var obj;
fs.readFile('dataFile.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  obj = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(obj.home)
});
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I need to fetch data from server using react in front end

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Did you try using [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)?

Comment: This is not assignment for school?

Comment: As i am learning react , i was trying to do this basic app.

Comment: @styfle No i dint .